# Structuring REST URLs and MVC

Tags: rest, model-view-controller

I have a service which has URLs that go a bit deep due to joined tables
To get all courses:

```
courses/
```

To get a single course:

```
courses/:courseid/
```

To get a course and it's topics:

```
courses/:courseid/topics
```

To get a topic and it's parts and it's bullet points:

```
courses/:courseid/topics/:topicid/
```

There are a few more layers that I omitted but my question regards MVC. If I need to get a list of courses or a single course I use the Course Controller but if the topics or a topic is requested, the Topic Controller is used. Does that mean I have to analyze the url args before redirecting the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a main endpoint class with one method to each url. It is more code, but I think is cleaner that check the args in only one endpoint method.